# Swift 3 : UIProgressView didn't update progress

Tags: ios, swift3

I write below codes to update progressView but it only reflect on screen when finished the loop and display 100% complete. Anything wrong?

```
@IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!

var totalCount = 100
var count = 0

for (_ in 0...100) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
       self.progressView.progress = Float(count) / Float(totalCount)
    })

    print("%: \(Float(count) / Float(totalCount))")

    count += 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not doing anything, so it will execute in almost no time.

You won't see the progressView update if you are effectively setting it to 100% with no delay.

Answer (score -1):

Please check :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!
    var progressBarTimer:Timer!
    var totalCount = 100
    var count = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.progressBarTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateProgressBar), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func updateProgressBar(){
        let progress = Float(count) / Float(totalCount)
        self.progressView.progress = progress
        print("%: \(progress)")
        if progress == 1.0 {
            progressBarTimer.invalidate()
        }
        count += 1
    }
}
```